# Cookie as image name and get value to set background

Tags: javascript, jquery, background

I wan't to set in cookie explorary image name, then get the value and set as background-image name.

```
<li class="bg"><a href="#"><img src="{style_images_url}/backgrounds/bac1.png" /></a></li>
```

There is code of my js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

   /* for thumbnail click event */
   jQuery('li.bg a').on('click',function(){
      jQuery("body").css('background-image', "url({style_images_url}/backgrounds/bac1.png)");
      jQuery.cookie("bgimg", "url({style_images_url}/backgrounds/bac1.png)", { expires: 7, path: '/'});
   });

   /* for page refresh */
   jQuery("body").css("background-image", "jQuery.cookie('bgimg')");
});
```

So, as you see I tried to get a cookie value and use it.
`jQuery.cookie('bgimg')` should include `url({style_images_url}/backgrounds/bac1.png)` - it's an address to my image.

So I have a problem with remembering the background, because all works good, background it's changing but after page refresh background is default.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

   jQuery("body").css({ "background-image": jQuery.cookie("bgimg") });

   jQuery("li.bg > a").on('click', function(){
      jQuery("body").css({"background-image": jQuery(this).attr('src')});
      jQuery.cookie("bgimg", "url("+ jQuery(this).attr('src') +")", { expires: 7});
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try removing quotes, as:

```
jQuery("body").css("background-image": jQuery.cookie('bgimg'));
```

or better check first if exists, and apply, if doesnt create the cookie:

```
if (jQuery.cookie('bgimg')) {
    jQuery("body").css("background-image": jQuery.cookie('bgimg'));
}
else {
    //set cookie
    jQuery.cookie("bgimg", "url({style_images_url}/backgrounds/bac1.png)", { expires: 7, path: '/'});
}
```

**Update::**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("body").css({ "background-image": $.cookie("bgimg") });

   $("li.bg > a").on('click', function(){
      $("body").css({"background-image": $(this).attr('src')});
      $.cookie("bgimg", "url("+ $(this).attr('src') +")", { expires: 7});
   });

});
```

Comment: Hello

I did something like that
`jQuery(document).ready(function(){

if (jQuery.cookie('bgimg')) {
    jQuery("body").css("background-image", jQuery.cookie('bgimg'));
}

else {
   jQuery('li.bg a').on('click',function(){
      jQuery("body").css('background-image', "url({style_images_url}/backgrounds/bac1.png)");
      jQuery.cookie("bgimg", "url({style_images_url}/backgrounds/bac1.png)", { expires: 7, path: '/'});
   });
}

});`

But now nothing works, so I think that the cookie exists but I can't get value of this. Have you other ideas how Can I change this code? Thank you.

Comment: what do you see when you do console.log(jQuery.cookie('bgimg'));

Comment: Sorry, in .js I'm really newbie. Can you tell me how should I start this console? Just past console.log(jQuery.cookie('bgimg')); after `jQuery(document).ready(function(){`? If yes, I see nothing.

Comment: Btw, did you include jquery.cookie.js script..?

Comment: Yes, yes, I did it :p I got this - https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/src/jquery.cookie.js

Comment: @Lawliet try with my updated answer.. it should work..!

Comment: @Lawliet and if you are directly adding this url:: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/src/jquery.cookie.js in your script tag, it wont work, you need to download the jquery.cookie.js from that link and include the actual js file

Comment: Sudhir - please look at the first post, where I updated code. In my script (it's IP.Board) I can't use "$" characters so I must replace it to "jQuery". With this code nothing works, even normal background change before refresh. Any ideas?